# How to set a checkbox to checked state in a ListView using Autohotkey

Tags: listview, checkbox, sendmessage, autohotkey

I am writing a Autohotkey script that need to 'check' and 'uncheck' checkboxes defined inside a listViewControl.

I think the way to do it is using a SendMessage to the listview (or maybe to the listview item itself?) using the LVM_SETITEMSTATE parameter
but i don't know the exact format...anyone have any idea?

```
SendMessage, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, 1000, SysListView321
```

i think that 1000 means that the checkbox will be checked and 2000 means that he will be unchecked.

do i need to do a loop for each ListViewItem?

I had also tried to use the

```
 LV_Modify(0, "+Checked")
```

But it doesnt seems to work also.

To emphasize the problem, I am not creating my own List View, i'm trying to manipulate the state of an exisiting application ListView....
(i'm running an installer and using the AutoHotKey script i press the next buttons on each of the screens, but  in this screen i need to first select all the components and only then move to the next screen)
Any AutoHotKey Experts in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of solving this issue ( a non elegant way) is :

```
ControlGet, List, List,, SysListView321,,,,
{    
    Loop, Parse, List, `n  ; Rows are delimited by linefeeds (`n).
    {           
        RowNumber := A_Index
        Loop, Parse, A_LoopField, %A_Tab%   ; Fields (columns) in each row are delimited by tabs (A_Tab).
        {                               
            if A_Index = 3 
            {               
                IfInString, HaystackTemp, %A_LoopField%
                {                       
                    ControlSend, SysListview321, {Space}                        
                }
            }
        }
        ControlSend, SysListview321, {Down}                         
    }
}
```

Do you know a more elegant way?